# Binding Javascript map to Aura Attribute map

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, map, aura-attribute

A similar question was asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213081/binding-javascript-objects-to-aura-attribute-collection-types) but unfortunately not appropriately answered.

I have my aura map declared as follows

```
<aura:attribute name="productInfoMap" type="Map" default="{}"
```

in my javascript controller I create the following:

```
let productInfoMap = new Map();
```

I'm not going to go into the very lengthy logic of assigning the map values but a console.log of the final result reads pretty normally:

```
Map(3) {"0WOP00000004XXXXX" => undefined, "0WOP0000000XXXXX" => Array(2), "0WOP0000000XXXXX" => Array(2)}
size: 3
__proto__: Map
[[Entries]]: Array(3)
0: {"0WOP0000000XXXXX" => undefined}
1: {"0WOP0000000XXXXX" => Array(2)}
2: {"0WOP0000000XXXXX" => Array(2)}
```

however, setting the aura attribute to the javascript map like so:

```
component.set("v.productInfoMap", productInfoMap);
```

and trying to access the values gives me the following error:

```
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Map
size: [Exception: TypeError: Method get Map.prototype.size called on incompatible receiver #<Map> at Map.get size [as size] (<anonymous>) at Map.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)]
__proto__: Map
```

What am I doing wrong? should I give up and just make a new js Object as opposed to a JS map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the `Map` type, just use object notation.

Instead of:

```
let productInfoMap = new Map();
```

Use:

```
let productInfoMap = {};
```

Also, better to use `const` if you don't reassign, which seems unlikely to be necessary in this scenario.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. Figured I'd have to give up on the map.